# Ubuntu 18.04 hangs on login screen after resume with NFS mounted prior to suspend

Tags: login-screen, nfs

I use NFS share in my local home network. NFS mount is defined in /etc/fstab as following:

```
192.168.1.1:/media/Share  /media/Share     nfs     noauto,rw,hard,intr,tcp,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,users 0 0
```

When I suspend my laptop with NFS share mounted (mount was done via clicking on the share name  in nautilus), then bring the laptop to my work place (where of course my NFS share is no longer available), resume it from suspend, enter password - it hangs there.

The only workaround I found is switch to VT3 (using ctrl+alt+f3), login there, unmount forcibly /media/Share, then switch back to VT2 and the graphical login will succeed.

Is this a bug? I used the same NFS mount on Ubuntu 17.10 and it had no issue with that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Once I understood that those random hangups on login were related to the mounted NFS share I've added a script with single command

```
umount -f /media/Share
```

to the `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` folder. That is executed before suspend, so on resume there is no NFS volume mounted.

Hope this workaround helps somebody else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I had already solved this issue same way Mario Welder described here. But in my case I put a file with execute permission in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` folder with following content:

```
#!/bin/sh

case $1 in
  pre)
    /bin/umount -lf /media/*
    ;;
esac
```

I am not sure whether it makes a big difference but anyway, for me it works since then.